# Django/Python and Raw SQL Querying with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

I'm practicing my raw SQL querying in a Django project using `cursor.execute`.

Here's my Django `models.py` database schema:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    date_incorporated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And here's the `psql` description of the table:

```
# \d+ client

      Column       |           Type           |      Modifiers     | Storage  |
-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------+
 date_incorporated | timestamp with time zone | not null           | plain    |
```

---

Here's where I get confused:

If I use `psql` to query the data from the table, I get:

```
# SELECT date_incorporated FROM client;

   date_incorporated    
------------------------
 2017-06-14 19:42:15-04
 2017-11-02 19:42:33-04
(2 rows)
```

This makes sense to me. In the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html), it shows that this is (I believe) just a string that is correctly formatted and stored as a UTC timestamp.

When I go through Django using this query:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT date_incorporated FROM client;')
data = [dict(zip(columns,row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

([*using the `dictfetchall` method from the Django docs*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly))

...my `date_incorporated` field gets turned into a python `datetime` object.

```
{'date_incorporated': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 2, 23, 42, 33, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

---

In this app I'm building, I wanted a user to be able to input raw SQL, and put that inputted string into the `cursor.execute(rawSQL)` function to be executed. I expected the output to be the same as the `psql` version.

If I was using the Django ORM, I might've expected the `timestamp with time zone` to be converted to a time-zone aware `datetime` object, but since I'm doing a raw SQL call, I expected to get back `2017-06-14 19:42:15-04`, not  a python `datetime` object.

Is the `fetchall` method still acting as the Django ORM and converting certain fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is standard conversion from using any interface driver.
You would get the same result even if you use py-postgressql, i.e. the cursor is doing the conversion according to the field type defined in the database.

Long story short, the dictfetchall is not doing any conversion, but rather parsing the converted result from the cursor.

Comment: Thank you. And the cursor is standard across all interface drivers you're saying? Most likely from [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)?